# HTTPWebrequest successfully fetched result even when wrong proxy credentials are given

Tags: vb.net, proxy, httpwebrequest

I am trying to hit a rest API using HttpWebRequest and I have to authenticate Proxy Server before I can hit a Rest API.

For authorizing proxy Server, I am adding credentials to HttpWebrequest.Proxy.credentials.

Now, my scenario is that, I am accessing the Rest API twice, first with Correct Proxy Credentials and then with wrong Proxy credentials.

With Correct Proxy Credentials I getthe out put as expected but with wrong credentials I am again able to fetch data from rest API.

If I reverse the order of APIs that is with wrong credentials first and then ith right creentials then I get 407 erro on 1st API hit which is correct.

How is this possible.

Here is my Code :

1st Call :

```
    Dim myHttpWebRequest As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(uri), HttpWebRequest)

    myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Proxy-Authorization", "Basic dXNlcjE6UGFzc3dvcmQx")

    myHttpWebRequest.Method = "GET"

    myHttpWebRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate Or DecompressionMethods.GZip Or DecompressionMethods.None

    Dim myHttpWebResponse = GetresponseForRequest(myHttpWebRequest)
```

2nd Call

```
    Dim myHttpWebRequest1 As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(uri), HttpWebRequest)

    myHttpWebRequest1.Headers.Add("Proxy-Authorization", "Basic dXNlcjE8UKFzc3dvcmQn")

    myHttpWebRequest1.Method = "GET"

    myHttpWebRequest1.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate Or DecompressionMethods.GZip Or DecompressionMethods.None

    Dim myHttpWebResponse1 = GetresponseForRequest(myHttpWebRequest)
```

Comment: Connections are managed by a [ServicePointManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager). Using the same endpoint, the managed connection doesn't change,

Comment: Can I reset it?

Comment: Try setting the `MaxServicePoints = 1` and/or play with the [MaxServicePointIdleTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.maxservicepointidletime). The KeepAlive property could also be used, but it's tricky, the connection might not survive if set to `False`.

Comment: See also this article: [Understanding MaxServicePointIdleTime and DefaultConnectionLimit](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2009/05/20/understanding-maxservicepointidletime-and-defaultconnectionlimit/) and this one: [Managing Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/managing-connections)